# Can't log in with email address

Tags: support, bug

I am logged onto this site from my work computer and I ticked 'remember me' (or whatever the box says; it was a few years ago now...!').

However when I try to log into this account from another computer , using the email address shown in my profile, I get the message "Could not find account for that email address". I have tried going into my profile and re-saving, even changing email address, and I consistently get the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

For some old weird reason, could you please try clearing all your browsing data (ctrl+shift+delete) or go to your browser incognito and try it again? Let's see if that will does the trick.

You may also want to check your *Account* > *Settings* tab > **Preferences section** to double check your email address from the computer you were able to access your Stackoverflow account.

Comment: It doesn't work in incognito, or a different browser. As far as I remember, these browsers have never been used to log into SO. I'm not sure what you want me to do in my preferences? I've already tried re-saving them, and changing email address... nothing is working